# How to continue the execution a step function in aws if one of the states in a parallel state fails?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have created following Step functions in my aws account. I have a requirement where I need to go to the `AddFun` state when `SayHi` state fails and `SayHello` state passes in the parallel state. Do AWS stepfunction allow us to do that? Or is there a work around to implement it?

[Step Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxPhB.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can add catcher to `SayHi`/`FailSayHi` (for specific errors so you won't ignore critical ones) and then whole parallel state will be successful. In error catcher you can add some data about error so you will be able to handle it (if needed) after parallel state completes (for example using Choice state).

Reference for catchers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-errors.html#amazon-states-language-fallback-states